# How can I set x-axis values in the Area Chart google visualisation

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Area chart by google visualisation. I need to customise the x-axis values.for example the date starts from 1 oct to 2 dec. In this I need to display only 10 values which includes the start date and the end date.

By default it displays like this.

```
    oct 1  oct 2  oct 3  oct 4  oct 5  oct 6  oct 7  oct 8  oct 9  oct 10
```

But I need in this format.

```
    oct 1  oct 7  oct 14  oct 21  oct 28  nov 4  nov 11  nov 18 nov 25  dec 2
```

and the values in between i.e., from start date to end date can be anything.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can specify your own values with the `ticks` option

Comment: But the starting and ending dates are not constant

Comment: Yeah, you will have to calculate mid values

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Get input the start date and end date well then calculate its difference. After getting the difference divide it in 10 intervals. Then assign these 10 intervals to the x-axis value.